# How to find usages of an Inteface used by Class.this in Intellij

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea

For example, I have an inteface *View.OnClickListener* implemented in *MainActivity* class:

```
public class MainActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
   @Override
   void onClick(View var1){
      // do things
   }
}
```

Later it is used using *this*:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
```

I want to locate just the code which use the *OnClickListener* of *MainActivity*. Does Intellij have a function to do that?

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/find-highlight-usages.html

Answer (score 0):

You can hold ctrl and and then left click on the method.